# “redefinition of 'foo' as different kind of symbol”

Tags: c, types, typedef, identifier, redefinition

I’m trying to refactor and bring-over some old code, and I ran across something like this:

```
          struct foo;
typedef   struct foo *    foo;
```

When attempting to compile it, I get the following sort of error:

> ```
> Source/Types/Types.h:27:18: error: redefinition of 'foo' as different kind of symbol
> typedef   struct foo *    foo;
>                  ^
> ```

Anybody know what’s causing this? I haven’t touched the code in a long time, but I *certainly* don’t remember any errors relating to that. It’s some of the most core code in the codebase, everything depends on it; I don’t see how I could possibly have missed such a glaring error, if it is indeed an error. Since the original `foo` is a “struct tag” (only a sane reference after the `struct` keyword), how can it conflict with my new `foo` typedef’d type?

**Edit 1:** Here’s the entire actual file, maybe I’m missing something, but it seems pretty straight-forward. It dumps a *slew* of the same errors described above, one for each type:

```
# if !defined(TYPE_DECLARATIONS)
#   define    TYPE_DECLARATIONS

# include "Core.h"
# warning "in Core.h"

static int class = 0; // to prove I’m not compiling as C++

          struct e(fork);
typedef   struct e(fork)*                 e(fork);

          struct e(execution);
typedef   struct e(execution)*            e(execution);


          struct e(thing);
typedef   struct e(thing)                 e(thing);

          struct e(typeRepresentation);
typedef   struct e(typeRepresentation)*   e(typeRepresentation);


struct e(typeRepresentation) {
  void *                      family;
  char                        name[64]; };

struct e(thing) {
  void * const                pointer;
e(typeRepresentation) const   isa; };


# endif //!defined(TYPE_DECLARATIONS)
```

(Also, ignore the `e()` macro; it’s a noop in this case.)

Comment: That code compiles no problem for me.  What compiler are you using?  I'm on gcc 4.3.3

Comment: It really appears you're trying to compile as `C++`. Try adding `int class;` somewhere suitable and check if the compiler complains :)

Comment: `static int class = 0;` in the global scope right before the other code results in no new errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, I solved my own problem. I managed to screw up my `e()` macro such that it was literally preforming a noop, removing the code in question. :O

I’m an idiot. Sorry for wasting everyone’s time.

Answer (score 2):

Are you now compiling this as C++, whereas it used to be compiled as C?

In C++, struct and enum tags live in the same namespace as other type names.

Comment: That sounds like the perfect explanation, except that I’m not. I wish it were that easy )-: (I’m using `clang -std=c99 -pedantic-errors -Wall -O0 ...`)

Comment: @sbi, no in C++ this more complicated than that. A `struct`, `union` or `enum` tag may be used as a type without the keyword *if* there is no other identifier (type, function, variable...) with that name.

Comment: @sbi: not completely. The code as it was given initially was not correct C++, because it made a `typedef` with different semantics than `struct foo`. But your second phrase is wrong. E.g `struct foo; foo* foo;` is valid C++, invalid in C. `struct foo foo; struct foo* foo;` is valid for both. `typedef struct foo foo;` also. But `typedef struct foo foo; foo* foo;` is then invalid for both.

Comment: @Jens: I see. I hadn't considered those. Is the fixed sentence now correct?

Comment: @sbi, hm, types and other identifiers live in the same namespace, and here we don't have transitivity... I'd go for something like "In C++, struct and enum tags can be used as type names if there is no ambiguity" or something like that. But anyhow, there are not much chances that someone will look into this now oldish question.

Answer (score 0):

you associate the name foo with two different types. struct foo and a pointer to struct foo are different types.